# Clear form data after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to programming and I'm using google spreadsheets to receive data from a simple registration form on my static site. Everything is working but I would like to reset the form data after sending the data. I already researched right here in the forum and I did not find any solution that did not erase the data for sending in the reset.

```js
<script>
  const scriptURL = 'url-sheet'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>
```

```html
<form class="apply" id="apply" name="submit-to-google-sheet">
        <div class="j-row apply-field">
          <div class="j-col j-col-3">
            <label for="Gamertag">Gamertag <span class="gold" title="Required field">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="j-col j-col-8 push-1">
            <input type="text" name="gamertag" placeholder="gamertag" maxlength="12" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j-row apply-field">
          <div class="j-col j-col-3">
            <label for="Discord">Discord <span class="gold" title="Required field">*</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="j-col j-col-8 push-1">
            <input type="text" name="discord" placeholder="usuário" maxlength="32" required>
            <span class="gold">#</span>
            <input type="number" name="id" placeholder="1234" maxlength="6" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j-row apply-field">
          <div class="j-col j-col-3">
            <label for="Refferal">Reference?</label>
          </div>
          <div class="j-col j-col-8 push-1">
            <input type="text" name="ref" placeholder="Name" maxlength="20">
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="submit" style="display:none" />
        <div class="j-row apply-field">
          <div class="j-col j-col-12">
            <button class="button full-width black" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the `form` back to its initial state call `reset()` on it. Given your logic it would make sense to do this after the AJAX request was successful, so place the call in the `then()` handler function:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)}).then(response => {
    console.log('Success!', response)
    form.reset();
  }).catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

Comment: Wow, this works quite simply, I have tried in many more complicated ways and none have, thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @RafaelaRodrigues Please mark this as the answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript:

```
$( '#apply' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById("apply").reset();`

```js
<script>
  const scriptURL = 'url-sheet'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
      
      document.getElementById("apply").reset();
  })
  
</script>
```